# Memory allocation when passing a std::vector to a function in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, parameter-passing, dynamic-memory-allocation

Consider the following simple example:

```c++
#include <vector>

void func(std::vector<int>* output) {
  std::vector<int> temp(10000);
  /* ... do work here and fill temp with useful values ... */

  // now send the result to main
  *output = temp;
}

int main(void) {
  std::vector<int> vec;
  // func will put useful values in vec
  func(&vec);

  for(size_t i=0; i<10000; i++)
    vec[i] = 3; // just checking to see if I get a memory error

  return 0;
}
```

I used to think one has to first allocate memory for `vec` before being able to use it (e.g., by calling `output->resize(10000)`?). Therefore I expected to get a memory error when using `vec` after calling `func` in the for loop, but it seems that the code works just fine.

Can you please explain this behavior? Also, is this how you'd write this code (i.e., when you need a function that is supposed to fill a vector, perhaps each time with a different number of values although here it's `10000`)? (PS. I don't want to use `return`).

Thanks!

Comment: You probably should pass the vector by reference instead of by pointer.

Comment: You can get away with this because the assignment operator for vector is designed this way. Objects that work in intuitive and easy ways get used a lot. Vector gets used a lot.

Comment: Thank to both of you. @drescherjm So in my actual code inside `func`, some other function is called to produce a (large) vector (similar to `temp`). Since that is a local variable (inside func), I'm not sure if passing by reference would work?

Comment: Note that reading a vector out of bounds using `operator[]` is Undefined Behaviour and doesn't guarantee a crash or error in any way. If you want to be sure of the size of your vector, you should simply query its `.size()` and check it directly against your expectations. Alternatively, you could use `.at(i)`, which throws an exception whenever `i` is out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for `std::vector`:

> The storage of the vector is handled automatically, being expanded and
> contracted as needed.

It is precisely this quality of `std::vector` that renders it quite easy to use.

In your code

```
*output = temp;
```

This line copies the `temp` vector into `output`, i.e., invoking the [assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D). You do not have to take care of how this is internally done, but you can assume that after that the vector pointed by `output` contains a copy of `temp`.

Comment: Thanks. So in my actual code inside `func`, some other function is called to produce a (large) vector (say `temp`). Is this the "right" way of passing the values of `temp` to main? (i.e., passing by pointer?)

Comment: Your C++ textbook should have a lengthy discussion of different ways to pass objects between functions: using pointers, references, and other approaches. There is no "right" way of doing something in C++ that's universally true in all situations. In order to make an intelligent decision as to the appropriate approach for the given situation it is necessary to fully understand what are the differences between the various options.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks Sam. So here is my specific situation: I have a function like main that calls another function (like `func` in the above example) to get a (large) vector of `int`. But `func` itself calls a third function that returns that vector inside `func`. Now I wonder what would be an appropriate way for passing this vector from `func` back to  main? (without using  `return` since it's already used for something else)

Comment: This is still too broad, and general, for a single solution to be identifiable. As I wrote: "in order to make an intelligent decision as to the appropriate approach for the given situation it is necessary to fully understand what are the differences between the various options", including pointers and references. And there is no law that says that only one value can be `return`ed from a function, anyway. This is what `std::tuple` is for. That doesn't mean that this would be the most optimal solution, it just goes to show the wide variety of available options.